# How do I check the status of Different Daemons in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am struggling to find out how to determine the status of different daemons in Hadoop. I know the status of only two daemons (namenode, jobtracker) since it is default in cloudera. How do I find the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Use *jps* (need *jdk* installed) to see all the daemons.

Besides jps, you can scan the results given by below to check if processes are running-

```
ps -ef | grep hadoop
```

You can also use the following once the server is running

```
./hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Another place to look at is the web interfaces of *namenode* and *jobtracker* for more details

Comment: No, what I meant is to check the status on web interfaces. For example, the status of namenode is something like <ipaddressofnamenode>.dfshealth.jsp